# k8s - Kubernetes - Service Update - Error

Tags: service, kubernetes

I'm trying to update a service using :

```
kubectl update service my-service \
    --patch='{ "apiVersion":"v1", "spec": { "selector": { "build":"2"} } }'
```

I receive the following Error :
`Error from server: service "\"apiVersion\":\"v1\"," not found`

I have tried the following :

- moving the service name to the end
- Removing the apiVersion

---

Maybe the kubectl update is not available for service ?

---

For now I was making my updates by simply stoping and restarting my service. But sometime, the corresponding forwarding-port changes. So it seems to not be the good choice ...

---

PS:

- v0.19
- api_v1

Comment: `kubectl update` [is going to be deprecated and replaced](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/kubectl_replace.md) by `kubectl replace`

For now it seems it is not usable (do not appear in kubectl CLI)


PS : `gcloud components update` responds with `All components are up to date.`

Comment: The kubectl version released with gcloud lags behind the latest release by a week or two (this should be much less noticeable once kubernetes reaches 1.0 and new minor releases are less frequent than every two weeks). In the meantime, you can manually grab a more recent kubectl binary from the release tarball.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if patch is 100% working yet, but if you are going to do this, you at least need to put apiVersion inside metadata, like so:

--patch='{ metadata:{ "apiVersion":"v1" }, "spec": { "selector": { "build":"2"} } }'

Comment: Thanks will try with that one